# Improving performance for grepping over a huge file

Tags: algorithms, performance, perl, bash

I have FILE_A which has over 300,000 lines and FILE_B which has over 30 million lines. I created a [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) script that greps each line in FILE_A over in FILE_B and writes the result of the grep to a new file.

This whole process is taking over 5 hours.

How can I improve the performance of my script?

I'm using `grep -F -m 1` as the grep command. FILE_A looks like this:

```
123456789 
123455321
```

and FILE_B is like this:

```
123456789,123456789,730025400149993,
123455321,123455321,730025400126097,
```

So with Bash I have a `while` loop that picks the next line in FILE_A and greps it over in FILE_B. When the pattern is found in FILE_B, I write it to file result.txt.

```
while read -r line; do
   grep -F -m1 $line 30MFile
done < 300KFile
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using `grep --file==FILE_A`.  It almost certainly loads the patterns into memory, meaning it will only scan FILE_B once.

```
grep -F -m1 --file==300KFile 30MFile
```

Comment: This would work only assuming I have enough memory right?

Comment: Honestly, I haven't tried it out myself on files of that size, but I believe it should dramatically improve your speed.  If you are on a modern machine, you should have no trouble holding a 300K file in memory.  (Or a 30M one for that matter.)

Comment: when i used the -f (--file) option it basically recreated the 30MFile. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Hmmm...maybe the 300Kfile had a blank line in it?

Comment: right on spot! that was it! that worked perfectly, it finished in 30 seconds! thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Here is a [Perl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl) answer for posterity. I routinely do this for matching 1M lines to 30-35M lines. It takes around 10 seconds to finish.

First, hash up FILE_A:

```
my %simple_hash;
open my $first_file, '<', 'FILE_A' or die "What have you done?! $!";
while (<$first_file>) {
  chomp;                 ## Watch out for Windows newlines
  $simple_hash{$_} = 1;  ## There may be an even faster way to define this
}
close $first_file;
```

Then, if your big file is delimited and know what column to go after, check for **just the existence** of the hash key as you run down FILE_B, which is much, *much* faster than checking for equality or regular expression matching:

```
open my $second_file, '<', 'FILE_B' or die "Oh no, not again.. $!";
while (<$second_file>) {
  my ($col1, undef) = split ',';
  if (exists($simple_hash{$col1}) {
    print $_;
  }
}
close $second_file;
```

If your larger target file isn't nicely parse-able, then this script loses its value as so much of its speed comes from not having to fire up the [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) engine.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some more involved programming, consider using [suffix trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree) (or a variant).

You can preprocess `FILE_B` using [Ukkonen's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukkonen%27s_algorithm) in linear time. Then, you query each line in `FILE_A` in time linear in line length and get all the line numbers that match (might need to adapt the tree a tad) which you can write to a result file.

The whole procedure runs in time O(n + Nm) if n is the length of `FILE_B`, `N` is the number of lines in `FILE_A` and m is the length of the longest line in `FILE_A` -- this is essentially linear runtime. Beats the quadratic time your original approach needs by magnitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I found the `--mmap` flag lately, didn't have a chance to test it, but I'll be happy to hear about your findings. Here is the description from man page:

```
--mmap If  possible, use the mmap(2) system call to read input, instead
      of the default read(2) system call.  In some situations,  --mmap
      yields  better performance.  However, --mmap can cause undefined
      behavior (including core dumps) if an input file  shrinks  while
      grep is operating, or if an I/O error occurs.
```

See [this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/mmap.html) or [this](http://useless-factor.blogspot.com/2011/05/why-not-mmap.html) for further info about `mmap`.

Comment: I'm definitely going to give this a shot and i'll let you know how it goes. How probable is that I will encounter a core dump?

Comment: @rogerio_marcio Well, as I understand the man, "if the file shrinks while grep is operating, or if an I/O error occurs.". Not really probably, but you should know this better. (If as I assume the file is untouched while grep - this should not happen)

Comment: For testing that `--mmap` dose not dump anything, I would recommend a run with `--mmap`, and one without. And then use `wc` to see that you have the same amount of output - this should be a robust test considering that we ran 2 times grep, and just a flag differed.

Comment: @rogerio_marcio Have you tried this? Any insights?

Answer (score -1):

why don't you put that file in a database
 databases are really good at doing an efficient merge,hash,nested loop join like this
. And they are really good at utilizing virtual memory

Comment: All you are doing with all the other answers is reinventing the database wheel